# Attempting a fluent API for creating random int arrays

Tags: c, array, multithreading, random, fluent-interface

I have attempted doing a fluent API for creating random `int` arrays, and the following is what I came up with:

**fluent_arrays.h:**

```
#ifndef FLUENT_ARRAYS_H
#define FLUENT_ARRAYS_H

#define REQUEST_THREAD_LOCAL 1

#ifdef REQUEST_THREAD_LOCAL
#define THREAD_LOCAL __thread
#else
#define THREAD_LOCAL 
#endif

/*******************************************************************************
* The maximum integer selector.                                                *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    int* (*with_maximum)(const int maximum);
} maximum_selector;

/*******************************************************************************
* The minimum integer selector.                                                *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    maximum_selector* (*with_minimum)(const int minimum);
} minimum_selector;

/*******************************************************************************
* The array length selector.                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    minimum_selector* (*of_length)(const size_t length);
} size_selector;

/*******************************************************************************
* Thread specific state.                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
static THREAD_LOCAL int    tl_api_initialised = 0;
static THREAD_LOCAL int    tl_minimum;
static THREAD_LOCAL size_t tl_length;

/*******************************************************************************
* Global state.                                                                *
*******************************************************************************/
static size_selector       gl_size_selector;
static minimum_selector    gl_minimum_selector;
static maximum_selector    gl_maximum_selector;

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements maximum integer selection and creation of actual array.           *
*******************************************************************************/
static int* impl_with_maximum(const int maximum)
{
    int* p_array = malloc(tl_length);
    const int minimum = tl_minimum;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < tl_length; ++i) 
    {
        p_array[i] = (rand() % (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
    }

    return p_array;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements minimum integer selection.                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
static maximum_selector* impl_with_minimum(const int minimum) 
{
    tl_minimum = minimum;
    return &gl_maximum_selector;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements array length selection.                                           *
*******************************************************************************/
static minimum_selector* impl_with_length(const size_t length) 
{
    tl_length = length;
    return &gl_minimum_selector;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Initiates the fluent API for creating random arrays.                         *
*******************************************************************************/
size_selector* create_random_array()
{
    if (!tl_api_initialised)
    {
        gl_size_selector.of_length = impl_with_length;
        gl_minimum_selector.with_minimum = impl_with_minimum;
        gl_maximum_selector.with_maximum = impl_with_maximum;

        tl_api_initialised = 1;
    }

    return &gl_size_selector;
}

#endif  /* FLUENT_ARRAYS_H */
```

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "fluent_arrays.h"

/*******************************************************************************
* Prints an integer array.                                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_int_array(const int *const p_array, const size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", p_array[i]);
    }

    puts("");
}

/*******************************************************************************
* The demonstration.                                                           *
*******************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    srand(time(NULL)); // <-- I know that this is not thread-safe.
    const size_t LENGTH = 30;

    // FUNKY FLUENT API IN C
    int* p_array = create_random_array()->of_length(LENGTH)
                                        ->with_minimum(-5)
                                        ->with_maximum(20);

    print_int_array(p_array, LENGTH);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

My main question is: how can I make this **thread-safe** (*nix, Mac OS X, Windows)?

Comment: It seems that your code uses C99 at least, but do you also accept C11 answers?

Comment: @Morwenn Yes, everything goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range limits of integer math: `rand() % (maximum - minimum + 1)`.

Should the user have `minimum == 0` and `maximum == RND_MAX` ( a reasonable situation) which might be `INT_MAX`, then code is attempting undefined behavior with `rand() % (INT_MAX + 1)`.  Also it is easy enough for the *width* of the inclusive range `[minimum ... maximum]` to be greater than `INT_MAX`.  A simple solution is to resort to a wider integer type.  [Example: int2x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982992/how-to-determine-integer-types-that-are-twice-the-non-padding-bits-as-int-and)

```
// some wider type
int2x diff = (int2x) maximum - minimum + 1;
p_array[i] = rand() % diff + minimum;
```

Now `diff` could exceed the range of `[0 ...RND_MAX]`.  In that case repeated calls to `rand()` (or other advanced schemes) are needed.

```
// Not highly efficient, but to show the point.
int2x r = (int2x) rand() * ((int2x) RND_MAX + 1) + rand();
p_array[i] = r % diff + minimum;
```

Using `%` can introduce random number generation bias.  I'll assume OP is familiar with that.  Many posts in SO discuss that like [Generating random numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067364/generating-random-numbers-in-c/3067387#3067387)

Minor: `create_random_array()` --> `create_random_array(void)` as the function should not accept any parameters.